# How to reduce the number of columns after One-hot encoding

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, jupyter, one-hot-encoding

I am working with a dataset that requires converting a categorical column into a numeric equivalent as the dataset requires a couple of ML techniques to be implemented. I used one-hot encoding technique to convert the categorical column (i.e. Nationalities) into numeric columns suitable for machine learning models. However, this technique tends to return a total of 227 columns. Just wanted to know if there is a way to reduce the number of columns obtained after implementing OHE. thanks.

The image is attached [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUpXg.png).

Comment: Why would you need to reduce the number of columns

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.factorize`.

```
df['Nationalities_numeric'] = pd.factorize(df['Nationalities'])[0]
print(df)

# Output
  Nationalities  Nationalities_numeric
0        France                      0
1         Spain                      1
2        Italia                      2
3        France                      0
4        Italia                      2
5       Germany                      3
```

Instead of `pd.get_dummies`:

```
df = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['Nationalities']))
print(df)

# Output
  Nationalities  France  Germany  Italia  Spain
0        France       1        0       0      0
1         Spain       0        0       0      1
2        Italia       0        0       1      0
3        France       1        0       0      0
4        Italia       0        0       1      0
5       Germany       0        1       0      0
```

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Nationalities': ['France', 'Spain', 'Italia',
                                     'France', 'Italia', 'Germany']})
```